# JQuery autocomplete - Select first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete which I am populating from a ruby on rails application and I am creating a custom autcomplete like so:

```
  $.widget( "custom.code_complete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
            var self = this,
                currentCategory = "";
        $ul = ul;
            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                    ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                    currentCategory = item.category;
                }
                self._renderItem( ul, item );
            });
        }
    });

  $("#r-code").code_complete({
    source: "URL",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $(".button-row").fadeIn();
      get_details(ui.item.url);
    }
  });
```

I am redirecting a user from another page to the page with the autocomplete form with a parameter in the URL which is a code used for the search, here is the JS to do the search:

```
function ac_search(code) {
  $("#r-code").val(code);
  $("#r-code").code_complete('search', code);
}
```

This performs the search perfectly and displays the drop down list of results.  I am trying to have the script then select the first result in the list.  I have tried doing it via a selector:

```
$(".ui-menu-item:first a").click();
```

This finds the correct element in the autocomplete list but when I try and simulate a click it gives this error:

```
TypeError: ui.item is null
```

Is it possible to programmatically click the first item in the autocomplete results list?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use autoFocus: true

```
 $( el ).autocomplete({
      autoFocus: true
      ...
 });
```

Comment: You don't really need this extension when you can just set the autoFocus option as true.

Answer (score 19):

```
$( el ).autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true
});
```